# option_groups_from_collection_for_select with a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It is possible to use option_groups_from_collection_for_select with a scope of the collection?

Instead of getting all the periods:

```
 option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Modality.all, :periods, :name, :id, :name)
```

I would like to get only the active ones:

```
 Period.active
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm,

You define a method in the grouping class:

```
class Modality < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :periods

  def active_periods
    periods.active
  end
end

class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modality

  scope :active, ->{ where(active: true)}
end

option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Modality.all, :active_periods, :name, :id, :name)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Brilliant, what a great solution Jorge! Quick note. If you want to use order, and you have other orders on the same model, you might need to force it with reorder, like this:

 scope :activedesc, -> { reorder(start_date: :desc) }